# Enquire other devices using same app in a local wi fi network

Tags: iphone, ios

Kindly suggest me way to enquire about other device using my app in same wi fi network.
Basically i want to know device name or any info about the device??

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/). Here's an example of P2P networking over local Wi-Fi: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000119i) to publish and scan for your app service on a local network.